# Build Dynamic query using Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am working on dynamic query building in LINQ using Expression Tree.

I have taken the reference to the following post
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq

How can I build expression if I want to check all the element in the list contains in another collection or not?

I have a Person class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a list

```
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person{ Name = "Shekhar", Age = 31},
            new Person{ Name = "Sandip", Age = 32},
            new Person{ Name = "Pramod", Age = 32},
            new Person{ Name = "Kunal", Age = 33}
        };
```

I have another list

```
List<string> nameList = new List<string>() { "Sandip", "Prashant" };
```

How can I build expression tree to check all the element in the list "nameList" contains in "personList" and give result true or false?

Comment: so what about article it doesn't hep you?

Comment: @welcome to stackoverflow!! you want to check For Name property  ?

Comment: Simply check if there is any element in PersonList that does not exitst in nameList or not: `!personList.Any(t=> nameList.Contains(t.Name))`

Comment: Why exactly do you need an expression tree. How it will help and not the simple match like Any() would do.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public bool Find(List<string> nameList, List<Person> personList)
    {
        foreach (var name in nameList)
            if (personList.FirstOrDefault(person => person.Name == name) != null)
            {
                // Find
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
bool contained = !personList.Select(l=>l.Name).Except(nameList).Any();
```